# Customized lock-free RingBuffer

Tags: c++, circular-list, lock-free, producer-consumer

I have implemented my own lock-free ringbuffer for multiple producers multiple consumers using vector. Can you guys help me review to see if there are any problems and ways to improve?

**Explanation:**
Each producer runs on its own thread and will use `Push()` to enter its item into the `RingBuffer`.

Each consumer runs on its own thread and has its own unique number. When consumer `TryRead()`, it will enter its unique number.

`RingBuffer` will keep track of the last position each consumer read in `std::vector<long> mReadIdxVec`

If `mReadIdxVec[consumer unique number] >= mMaxReadIdx`, `TryRead()` will return a `nullptr`.

**Question:**
Within `Push()` method, will it be a problem if multiple producers on different threads call this line `mVector[index] = pMsg;` at the same time?

Can this code be improved further? Any comments are welcomed!

---

RingBuffer.h

```
#ifndef __RING_BUFFER_H_
#define __RING_BUFFER_H_

#include <atomic>

class RingBuffer
{
    private:
        std::vector<Foo *> mVector;
        std::atomic<long> mWriteIdx{0}; //mWriteIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
        std::atomic<long> mMaxReadIdx{0}; //mMaxReadIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
        std::vector<long> mReadIdxVec;

    public:
        RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers);
        void Push(Foo *);
        Foo * TryRead(const int&);
};

#endif
```

---

RingBuffer.cc

```
#include "RingBuffer.h"
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers) 
{
    mVector.reserve(MAX_SIZE);
    mVector.assign(MAX_SIZE, nullptr);
    mReadIdxVec.assign(pNumOfConsumers, 0);
}

void RingBuffer::Push(Foo * pMsg)
{
    if(!pMsg) return;
    long writeIdx = mWriteIdx++;
    long index = writeIdx % MAX_SIZE;
    if(writeIdx >= MAX_SIZE) delete mVector[index];
    mVector[index] = pMsg;
    mMaxReadIdx++;
}

Foo * RingBuffer::TryRead(const int& pConsumer) 
{
    if(mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] >= mMaxReadIdx) return nullptr;
    long index =  mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] % MAX_SIZE;
    mReadIdxVec[pConsumer]++;
    return mVector[index];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I see a `Foo` in your code. Who's that and where did he come from? For future reference, please take a look at the [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: Have you seen Tony Van Eerd's talks on [Lock-Free Queues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu6XB-WRNxs)?

Comment: Is it intended that each consumer individually has to visit every item pushed into the ringbuffer? Elements already processed by other consumers don't seem to get skipped.

Comment: Yes it is intended for each consumer to visit every item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have comments in the definition of `RingBuffer` on the value limits for some members, but there is nothing in the code that enforces that or checks to see if those limits are exceeded.

Why does `TryRead` take its parameter by `const int&`?  The reference is unnecessary.  Just pass in the int.

Why is `MAX_SIZE` a macro?  It should be a `constexpr` (if your compiler supports it) or `static const int` if not.

In the `RingBuffer` constructor, you can combine the `reserve` and `assign` calls into one, and include it in the member initializer list.

`Push` will happily and silently overwrite things that have been added to your ring buffer but not consumed.

The way your `Push` is set up, you can have multiple threads write to the same memory location (if, for instance, there are enough other calls to `Push` so that the value calculated for index wraps back around).

It is also possible for `mMaxReadIdx` to indicate a slot is available for reading when it isn't.  For example, thread A starts a Push, and gets a write index.  Thread B then starts another Push, gets a write index, stores its value and increments `mMaxReaddx` before thread A has stored its message.  The slot used by thread A will be readable by a `TryRead` but won't have data in it yet.

`TryRead` can return the same message to multiple consumers, since each consumer has its own idea of where the bottom of the buffer is.

```
RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers): mVector(MAX_SIZE, nullptr)
```

Comment: "mMaxReadIdx to indicate a slot is available for reading when it isn't".  Thanks for pointing this out! :)  I will have to think of a way to prevent this.. If anyone have some ideas, please share!

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the unnecessary reference in TryRead and MAX_SIZE as macro.

Comment: I am not too worried about the limits not being enforced cause I am certain they won't be exceeded for my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem of `mMaxReadIdx` being incremented by Thread B before Thread A has stored its message, could we consider the use of an atomic boolean as below?

---

Ringbuffer.h

```
#ifndef __RING_BUFFER_H_
#define __RING_BUFFER_H_

#include <atomic>

class RingBuffer
{
    private:
      std::vector<Foo> mVector;
      std::atomic<long> mWriteIdx{0}; //mWriteIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
      std::atomic<long> mMaxReadIdx{0}; //mMaxReadIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
      std::vector<long> mReadIdxVec;
      std::atomic<bool> mIsPushing{false};

    public:
      RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers);
      void Push(Foo);
      Foo * TryRead(int);
};

#endif
```

---

```
#include "RingBuffer.h"

static constexpr int const& MAX_SIZE = 5000;

RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers) 
{
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        Foo f;
        mVector.push_back(f);
    }
    mReadIdxVec.assign(pNumOfConsumers, 0);
}

void RingBuffer::Push(Foo pMsg)
{
    long writeIdx = mWriteIdx++;
    long index = writeIdx % MAX_SIZE;
    while(mIsPushing.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)){};
    mIsPushing.store(true,std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    if(writeIdx >= MAX_SIZE) delete mVector[index];
    mVector[index] = pMsg;
    mMaxReadIdx++;
    mIsPushing.store(false,std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

Foo * RingBuffer::TryRead(const int& pConsumer) 
{
    if(mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] >= mMaxReadIdx) return nullptr;
    long index =  mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] % MAX_SIZE;
    mReadIdxVec[pConsumer]++;
    return mVector[index];
}
```

---

Ringbuffer.h (Lock-free)

```
#ifndef __RING_BUFFER_H_
#define __RING_BUFFER_H_

#include <atomic>

class Foo
{
    public:
        long bar = 0;
        double bar2 = 0;
        std::atomic<bool> isSetting{false};

        void set(long pBar, double pBar2)
        {
            isSetting = true;
            bar = pBar;
            bar2 = pBar2;
            isSetting = false;
        }
        Foo(){};
        Foo(const Foo &m2) //copy constructor required as they are default-deleted for atomics
        {
            set(m2.bar, m2.bar2);
        }
};

class RingBuffer
{
    private:
      std::vector<Foo> mVector;
      std::atomic<long> mWriteIdx{0}; //mWriteIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
      std::atomic<long> mMaxReadIdx{0}; //mMaxReadIdx will not exceed 2,000,000,000
      std::vector<long> mReadIdxVec;

    public:
      RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers);
      void Push(Foo);
      Foo * TryRead(int);
};

#endif
```

---

```
#include "RingBuffer.h"

static constexpr int const& MAX_SIZE = 5000;

RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int pNumOfConsumers) 
{
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        Foo f;
        mVector.push_back(f);
    }
    mReadIdxVec.assign(pNumOfConsumers, 0);
}

void RingBuffer::Push(Foo pMsg)
{
    long writeIdx = mWriteIdx++;
    long index = writeIdx % MAX_SIZE;
    mVector[index].set(pMsg.bar, pMsg.bar2);
}

Foo * RingBuffer::TryRead(const int& pConsumer) 
{
   if(mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] >= mWriteIdx) return nullptr;
   if(mVector[index].isSetting) return nullptr;
   long index = mReadIdxVec[pConsumer] % MAX_SIZE;
   mReadIdxVec[pConsumer]++;
   return &mVector[index];
}
```

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: That's basically a spin lock, so not exactly lock-free. I don't think that's intended by the OP. A truly lock-free solution could add a `std::atomic<bool>` per element in the ringbuffer which indicates whether said element is ready to be read. // Also, the acquisition of the spin lock isn't correct. Multiple threads might read `mIsPushing` as `false` before some thread stores `true` in it again. A better approach would use `compare_exchange_strong`.

Comment: @hoffmale do you mean using `compare_exchange_strong` instead of using `store`?

Comment: I was originally thinking of replacing `while(mIsPushing.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)){}; mIsPushing.store(true,std::memory_order_seq_cst);` with `auto expected = false; while(!mIsPushing.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) expected = false;`. Thinking about it some more, I realized that this could be simplified to `while(mIsPushing.exchange(true));`. // The problem in the original snippet is the gap between checking `mIsPushing` and setting it. A thread might read `false`, but before it is able to set `mIsPushing` to `true`, some other thread might also have read `false`.

Comment: Ah yes what you said is similar to the example here as well: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @hoffmale I did up a revised lock-free (?) version in my post based on your suggestion. Would this be closer to what you had in mind?

Comment: `Foo::isSetting` should be `false` by default, I guess. `Foo(const Foo&)` should call `set` to copy the members. `while(mVector[index].isSetting.load()){};` is a spinlock (again), but could be replaced by `if(mVector[index].isSetting) return nullptr;` to make it lock-free. Oh, and you don't need `maxReadIdx` anymore, the check in `TryRead` can compare to `mWriteId` instead.